# Graeco-Latin squares and outer-automorphisms

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-groups, combinatorial-designs

It is well known that $n=6$ is the only number greater than two in which there is no Graeco-Latin square of order $n$. It is also well known that $n=6$ is the only number greater than two in which there is an outer automorphism of the symmetric group $S_n$. Is there a connection between these two interesting facts or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: Why greater than 2?  There is also no outer automorphism of $\mathrm S_0 \cong \mathrm S_1$ or $\mathrm S_2$.

Comment: I just wanted to keep things nontrivial.